# Mark all methods as "safe"

Tags: php, twig

I want to create a class full of HTML helper methods:

```
class FormHelper {
    public function text() {
        return 'hello <b>world</b>';
    }
}
```

Which I register as a global:

```
$twig->addGlobal('fh',new FormHelper);
```

Then I can call the methods from Twig:

```
{{ fh.text }}
```

But they're always escaped (e.g. `hello &lt;b&gt;world&lt;/b&gt;`).

I know I can prevent escaping with `|raw`, but I want to bypass this, the same way you can [designate a function as safe](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#automatic-escaping).

Is this possible for class methods?

Answer (score 1):

Twig Globals is just a storage where you can put any variable that will be available in the context. No logic is applied, just as if those variables were stored in the local context.

But you can iterate your class's methods and register them as safe functions:

```
$object = new FormHelper();
foreach (get_class_methods($object) as $method)
{
    $function = new Twig_SimpleFunction("fh_{$method}", array($object, $method), array('is_safe' => array('html')));
    $twig->addFunction($function);
}
```

Note that you can't use a dot (`.`) in function name, so you'll need to call:

```
{{ fh_test() }}
```